# ShareThis Sees http and https as different page

Tags: wordpress, sharethis

We recently went from http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com to allow for a more secure online environment. This was done partly to allow for on-site donations.

We utilize a social sharing tool called ShareThis ([www.sharethis.com](http://www.sharethis.com)). Our home page has received several thousand likes and "ShareThis" clicks over the past year. Unfortunately all of these are now gone when changed to https.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1) Change from https:// back to http://

2) Ask the company to update your website in their database and/or update their software to recognize that http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com are the same website.

So, those are two options if you're willing/able to switch back to http://, otherwise, omit option 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the URL that you pass to the widget. Pass it the http URL so that is what will get shared and that's the counts you will get..

I wrote the ShareThis widget so let me know if this works for you..